# Rotate, Drag , Zoom in, Zoom out Video and image in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-imageview, android-videoview, android-mvvm

I need a library which performs zoom in, zoom out, rotate, and drag like Instagram status has For both images and video.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/burhanrashid52/PhotoEditor

You can use this lib for some Features

Comment: Thank you but not full fill my answer

Comment: Cannot found how to zoom or rotate.